# PHP PDO query, optimize speed performance over 10 million rows MS ACCESS database

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access, pdo, etl

I have to import an MS Access database into MySQL. One of the tables has almost 10 million records. I am trying to do a pagination of 4000 rows each time. The problem is that the MS Access query lasts for over 35 seconds (35 seconds in a 4000 rows pagination is about 24 hours...).

This is the code for the MS Access connection:

```
$dataSourceName = "odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=".$this->dbPath."; Pwd=";
$this->connection = new PDO($dataSourceName, "", "");
$sql = "SELECT TOP $pageSize * FROM $table WHERE $table.$primaryField > $lastIndex ORDER BY $table.$primaryField";
$rs  = $this->connection->query($sql)->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

`$primaryField` is, in Access, an integer (primary key).

How could I speed this query? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please try this one https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-database-access.html and let run

Comment: Have you considered binary Tree?

Comment: Binary tree? Dont understand @Nelles

Comment: @nbk This migrations is not one time, I have to do it periodically and programatically. The new records has to be inserted and the old one updated if changed. My algorithm is ready, but is this piece of code which lasts 35 seconds per cycle

Comment: then add in mysql also the index, if is not set until now

Comment: @nbk I have added the index on MySQL, but the problem is retrieving data from ms access, it lasts 35 seconds to get the data

Comment: @Nelles I have studied the binary tree option, This is what I have found `Not really, because Access (better: Jet) does not support recursive
queries. SQL Server 2005 does, so perhaps the free Express Edition is
something you should be looking at`

Comment: I don't think that 35 seconds are that excessive, but i wouldn't use php for that either Odbc is old and slow, access is old and slow. You could try to reduce the number of rows that get selected by refining the where clause.

Comment: @nbk 35 seconds are not that excesive for an access table with such size. But I need to import multiple times a day, with 35 seconds query it is impossible. What would you use for this instead of PHP?

Comment: @JavierTorrónDíaz ok (regarding binary tree) good to see you have considered every option.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-linked-tables.html  where you update directly mysql.

Comment: Thats the problem, I cannot connect to the original Access database because is in use and compacting. I get a copy of that access db every 15 minutes, so I cannot do the mysql links.

Comment: How do you compute $lastindex?  Do you reconnect for each clump?  (Don't)

Comment: Please provide the schema definition for both the source table and the destination table.

Comment: Can you disable the "compacting" during the ETL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task is generically called **ETL** for extract-transform-load.

You have some alternatives to speed this up.

- try bigger batches of rows (pages). It's possible that fetching 40K rows may be much faster per row than 4K rows using your ODBC interface.
- Access has a "Compact and Repair Database" command in the Tools or Manage section of the user interface. Maybe cleaning it up will make your operations faster, especially if the database has been in use for a while. Back it up first.  This takes downtime.
- export the Access table to a .csv file on your filesystem, then use LOAD DATA INFILE to import it into MySQL. The .csv export may be substantially faster than your odbc queries.
- rewrite your extract / transfer / load program in dotnet (C#). dotnet has a native, rather than ODBC, interface for reading access files and may be a whole lot faster.

ETLing ten million rows is going to take a while no matter how many clever tricks you use.

It seems unlikely that all ten million of your Access rows change multiple times a day. If there's a way to extract / transform / load only the changed rows, that is your best bet. But it's a probably a data change, and you probably don't want to touch that Access application.

Comment: I wish I could touch that Access application, but is far from my hand. I will test the third first points, because the fourth is something I cannot do (my customer wants old PHP 5.6 in a Debian 8 machine ....)

Comment: You can run a .Net app on another machine (windows) and connect to mysql on debian, or on linux you can use [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/). But if I where you, I would convince customer to improve environment (migrate to MySQL or SQL Server as backend) or he has to pay me quadruple for the pain caused.